# PHPでシンボリックリンクを含む圧縮ファイルを解凍したい

Tags: php

Mac OSX上でPHP 5.6.2を使っています。

以下のディレクトリ構成を`zip -ry`して圧縮ファイルを作成しました。
このファイルをunzipコマンドで解凍すると、シンボリックリンクを正しく抽出できるのですが、PHPのZipArchiveクラスを使って解凍すると、ただのファイルになってしまいます。

PHPを使って、シンボリックリンクを正しく解凍するよい方法はないでしょうか？
なお、圧縮ファイルの種類や、PHPのライブラリの種類は問いません。

#### 圧縮ファイルの作成

シンボリックリンクを含んでいます。

```
$ tree samples
samples
├── symlinks
│   ├── text1.txt -> ../text1.txt
│   └── text2.txt -> ../text2.txt
├── text1.txt
└── text2.txt

$ zip -ry samples.zip samples
```

#### unzipで解凍

シンボリックリンクを正しく解凍できています。

```
$ unzip samples.zip -d tmp
$ tree tmp
tmp
└── samples
    ├── symlinks
    │   ├── text1.txt -> ../text1.txt
    │   └── text2.txt -> ../text2.txt
    ├── text1.txt
    └── text2.txt
```

#### PHPで解凍

シンボリックリンクがただのファイルになってしまいました。

```
$ php unzip.php 
$ tree tmp
tmp
└── samples
    ├── symlinks
    │   ├── text1.txt
    │   └── text2.txt
    ├── text1.txt
    └── text2.txt
```

PHPの解凍用プログラム

```
<?php // unzip.php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("samples.zip");
$zip->extractTo("tmp");
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`php5.6.0`で追加された[`getExternalAttributesIndex`](http://php.net/manual/ja/ziparchive.getexternalattributesindex.php)を利用するとシンボリックリンクかどうかが判定できます。

```
<?php

function extractToSym($zip, $dir)
{
  for ($idx=0; $s = $zip->statIndex($idx); $idx++) {
    if ($zip->getExternalAttributesIndex($idx, $opsys, $attr) && $opsys == ZipArchive::OPSYS_UNIX) {
      if ((($attr >> 16) & 0120000) === 0120000) {
        symlink($zip->getFromIndex($idx), $dir . '/' . $s['name']);
      } else {
        $zip->extractTo($dir, $s['name']);
      }
    }
  }
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('samples.zip') === TRUE) {
  extractToSym($zip, '.');
  $zip->close();
}
```

**追記:**

zipファイルの`ExternalAttributes`について、ドキュメントは見つかりませんでしたが[`Info-ZIP`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/?source=typ_redirect)のソースコードを見る限りでは、この数値は`stat`構造体の`st_mode`フィールドの値を16bit左にシフトしたもののようです。

```
*a = ((ulg)s.st_mode << 16) | !(s.st_mode & S_IWRITE);
```

[`sys/stat.h`](http://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)ではシンボリックリンクのフラグが`0120000`と定義されています。

ソースコードを見る限りではwindowsでも似たような構造になっているようですが、手元に確認できる環境がないので詳しくは分かりません。

Comment: $attrの値がどの様な物か知りたいのですが、どこかにドキュメントはあるでしょうか？OS依存の値らしいのですが、UNIXやWindowsだとどの様な値なのでしょう？

Comment: ググっても出てこない、とても貴重な解凍いや、回答だと思います。ありがとうございます。